# Как при помощи js или python получить размер окна браузера и передать этот размер в css файл?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, css3

Как при помощи js или python получить размер окна браузера и передать этот размер в css файл ?
Предположим у меня есть следующий блок div:

```
    <div class="saitpage"></div>
```

и css файл:

```
    .saitpage {
       margin-left: здесь должен быть размер окна;
    }
```

Как мне передать полученный размер окна в css файл ?

Comment: Думаю вы легко решите свою проблему если почитаете про [переменные в таблицах стилей](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp) и [их взаимодействие с джаваскрипт](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables_javascript.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, про какой размер окна браузера идет речь. Могу предположить, что про размер самой веб-страницы, то есть ширины отображаемого содержимого (отрендеренного контента).

```js
const pageWidth = document.documentElement.scrollWidth;
document.querySelector('.saitpage').style.marginLeft = pageWidth + 'px';
```

```css
.saitpage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="saitpage"></div>
```

Comment: Салам  js, jQuery  не умеют записывать в файл

Comment: а есть какая-нибудь возможность записать скрипт в файл css ?